# In Swift 2.2, how do I concisely specify an anonymous function that may throw

Tags: swift, lambda, swift2

Here is a stripped down sample from my code:

```
struct Widget {
    let string: String
    init(_ string: String) throws {
        self.string = string
    }
}

struct Widgets {
    let widgets: [Widget]

    init(_ strings: [String]) throws {
        // Is this really the cleanest way to do the map?
        widgets = try strings.map({(string:String) throws -> Widget in
            return try Widget(string)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw. I'm using XCode 7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.map` marked with `rethrows` keyword so you can just

```
init(_ strings: [String]) throws {
    widgets = try strings.map(Widget.init)
}
```

since `Widget.init` throws `.map` also throws